# AWS-CLI ElaticBeanstalk:To create a new application version from local war file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I am unable to create new application version from local war file using aws-cli.
if my war file store in S3 Bucket so this command helpful for me

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name my-application --version-label v2 --source-bundle S3Bucket=my-bucket,S3Key=test-proxy-sample.war
{
"ApplicationVersion": {
    "ApplicationName": "my-application",
    "VersionLabel": "v2",
    "SourceBundle": {
        "S3Bucket": "my-bucket",
        "S3Key": "test-proxy-sample.war"
    },
    "DateUpdated": "2015-07-07T22:03:49.013Z",
    "DateCreated": "2015-07-07T22:03:49.013Z"
}
}
```

What should I do if war file store in my local system?
Is there any way to upload war file from local to elastic beanstalk application version using aws-cli
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the new [eb cli v3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) which works with git. basically you commit your war to a local git and deploy it to beanstalk.

```
git init
git add my.war
git commit -am 'commit for beanstalk'
eb deploy <envname>
```